# PHP Custom router: Pass variable with template

Tags: php, router

I am learning about Routers without the use of an .htaccess file to make readable urls. So I achieved to do just that. Now I want to make it work to render a template and have variables send with the template. Let me explain further with my code.

// Router

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use Closure;

class Router
{
    public array $routes = [];

    public function Route($action, Closure $callback)
    {
        $action = trim($action, '/');
        $action = preg_replace('/{[^}]+}/', '(.*)', $action);
        $this->routes[$action] = $callback;
    }

    public function Dispatch($action)
    {
        $action = trim($action, '/');

        $callback = null;
        $params = [];

        foreach ($this->routes as $route => $handler) {
            if (preg_match("%^{$route}$%", $action, $matches) === 1) {
                $callback = $handler;
                unset($matches[0]);
                $params = $matches;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$callback || !is_callable($callback)) {
            http_response_code(404);
            Page::httpResponseCode404();
            exit;
        }

        return call_user_func($callback, ...$params);
    }
}
```

Then I have my routes configured in a different file

// Routes

```
<?php


use App\Core\Page;

$route = new \App\Core\Router();

$route->Route('/', function() {
    Page::Load('Home/index');
});

$route->Route("/user/id/(.*)", function($id) {
    Page::Load("User/test", $id);
});

$action = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$route->Dispatch($action);
```

The above code works perfectly passing the url as variable when just doing it as following.

```
$route->Route("/user/id/(.*)", function($id) {
    return "My id is: {$id}";
});
```

To make my life easier I created a small class to import the views from my folder. But I am lost and might be to tight to my code to see what I am doing wrong in order to pass the variable to the template itself.

Here my Page (class) to Load in my views

// Page

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

class Page
{
    public static function Load($page, $params = [] ?? '') {
        if (file_exists(ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . $page . '.php')) {
            self::Header();
            include ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . $page . '.php';
            self::Footer();
        }

    }

    public static function httpResponseCode404() {
        if (file_exists(ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . 'httpResponseCode')) {
            if (http_response_code(404)) {
                self::Header();
                include ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . 'httpResponseCode' . DS . '404.php';
                self::Footer();
            }
        }
    }

    protected static function Header() {
        if (file_exists(ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . 'header.php')) {
            include ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . 'header.php';
        }
    }

    protected static function Footer() {
        if (file_exists(ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . 'footer.php')) {
            include ROOT_DIR . DS . '..' . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . LAYOUT . DS . 'footer.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone put me in the right direction on explaining how it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I been trolling myself all along.
Been over every piece of code again and the solution was already within the code itself.

By doing the following in the Routes file I got it working.

```
$route->Route("/user/id/(.*)", function($id) {
    $params = [
        'id' => $id,
        'test' => "testing this damn thing!"
    ];
    Page::Load('User/test', $params);
});
```

I hope this will help others as well when building their tiny applications without any framework and using pure php.